# Getting only NAs in the dataframe?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a dataframe with two columns and 10 rows whereby the first column contains weight (denoted by w in the code) and the second column contains the error rate (denoted by cv.error). However I get a dataframe with only NA in it. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Help would be appreciated.

I want a dataframe in which the first column has "w" and the other has cv.error.

Following is my code

```
l <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 2))

k_fun <- function(combined_distance,n,j)
{
   glm_fit <- glm(gcms$train$response ~ combined_distance ,family=binomial, data=gcms$train,control = list(maxit = 50))
   cv.error = cv.glm(gcms$train, glm_fit,K=5)$delta[1]
   l[j,1] = n
   l[j,2] = cv.error
}

w = c(0.1,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45,0.50,0.7,0.9)

for(j in 1:10)
{
   combined_distance <- alkoloiddistance + (1 - alkoloiddistance^w[j]) *   solventdistance
   k_fun(combined_distance,w[j],j)
}
```

Comment: @R-Fever "Could u show what gcms, alkoloiddistance and solventdistance is?

u possibly need   `l[j,1] <<- n` and `l[j,2] <<- cv.error`. You hope to update the data frame within the function, but actually it is only its local copy inside the function that is updated. so after running your loop, your data frame in your r session is unchanged at all. "

Comment: @R-Fever...Thanks I tried what you said and it's working just the way I want my code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont know why my answer was deleted. it answered the question, and it explained the reason.

u need `l[j,1] <<- n` and `l[j,2] <<- cv.error`. u hope to update `l` inside the function, but actually it is only its local copy in the function that is updated. so after running your loop, `l` in your r session is unchanged at all. u set up `l` as a data frame of NA, thus u still get a data frame with all NA.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related to how you instantiated the data frame.  If you run `str(l)` after running the first line of your code you may see that the data type assigned by R is either logical or factor.  If you try to assign numeric values to columns of these types you will get an `NA` instead.  Try running `options(stringsAsFactors = F)` before the rest of your code.  Alternatively, you can assign the class of NA you want in the first line of your code (e.g., `NA_integer_`).